# ubuntu and laptops or mini-laptops

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, drivers

I'm planning to buy a laptop or mini-laptop and use an Ubuntu OS on it. The thing is that i really need it to use it many hours on battery mode. I'm thinking that I'll have troubles in finding the right drivers and my battery to be wasted. What other problems can I have?

Also, I want to use the laptop or mini-laptop outside/outdoor. What display technology is most recommended for that?

Comment: I can't edit here, so: "here" => "there", "planing" => "planning", "a Ubuntu" => "an Ubuntu", "batery" => "battery", "rivers" => "drivers", "waisted" => "wasted", "wana" => "want to" (or "wanna").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> i really need it to use it many
>   hours on batery mode. I'm thinking
>   that i'll have troubles in finding the
>   right rivers and my batery to be
>   waisted.

Generally, Ubuntu has pretty decent driver support, so usually you'll get decent battery life. To be sure, just look up other people's experiences with a given system (e.g. on http://www.linux-laptop.net/ or http://www.tuxmobil.org/ ). Or buy a system that comes with Linux preinstalled.

> Also, I wana use the laptop or
>   mini-laptop outside/outdoor. What
>   display technology is most recommended
>   for that?

Well, ideally you'd use some kind of e-ink technology (like the OLPC laptop or the Amazon Kindle does), but I don't know of any laptops that use that.

Your best bet is to just look up review for laptops you consider and see what they say about readability in the sun. You probably want a non-glossy screen (less reflections), and a bright display.

Answer (score 2):

This is a subjective answer, intended to be just one opinion of many.

I've recently bought an Asus eeePC 1005PE and put Ubuntu Netbook Remix on it.
It was advertised as having 11hrs battery life.
I haven't put this to the test, but I must say I have been very impressed with the battery, as I didn't charge it for a week, only using an hour or two a day.

As for outdoor use, I used it in the car on a sunny day once, and didn't have too much of a problem. It's got an anti-reflect matt coating on the screen which helps.
There is currently a known problem with brightness on these netbooks, but there's also a workaround to fix brightness on the maximum level.

Hope it helps, comment here for more details if you want to know how to fix the brightness problem and I'll dig out the link.